# When changing sort order - focus jumps to search field

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, stack-overflow-app

The default sort order for questions is active, whenever I change it the something else (usually newest), the focus goes to the search field, causing the keyboard to slide up and obstruct half the screen.

Can we please not focus to the search field after changing sort order? If I want to search the list, I can touch the search field myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.1, going live now.

I had no idea why this was happening and it's been bugging me for a while so thanks for giving me a reason to do a deep dive :)

The search box being the first item in the view was causing it to get focus in a lot of situations, the sort spinner changing being one.

The weird fix was telling Android the parent view containing the search text and the spinner is itself focusable, which means when something happens and the system searches for what to give focus to that parent view gets the focus, versus the search text.